# @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn with Bidirectional @OneToOne relationship

Tags: hibernate, orm

I have two objects Mat and MatImage, parent and child resp. The primary key of MatImage is the id of Mat and they are join by one to one relationship.

If I understand bidirectional relation correctly, the child object would know about the parent if I do something like matImage.setMat(mat). I would think the primary key would be filled at this point, but it doesn't. I know this because sql throws an exception when it try to insert MatImage with #0 as matId.

Another question is with the n+1 problem. I would like to lazily load child object because not all mat has matimage. I can try changing @OneToOne to @ManyToOne but not sure how that can be done bidirectionally. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Here are the entities:

```
// Mat

@Entity
@Table(name="mat")
public class Mat implements Serializable {
 @Id
 @GeneratedValue(generator="SeqMat")
 @SequenceGenerator(name="SeqMat", sequenceName="seq_mat_id")
    int id

    @OneToOne(mappedBy="mat", optional=true, fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
 @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name="id", referencedColumnName="matId")
 @Cascade([ALL, DELETE_ORPHAN])
 MatImage matImage

    int matTemplateId
    int number
    ... 
}


     // MatImage
    @Entity
    @Table(name="matimage")
    public class MatImage implements Serializable {
        @Id
        int matId

        @OneToOne(optional=true, fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
        @JoinColumn(name="matId", referencedColumnName="id")
        Mat mat

        @Column(name="img_eventid")
        int eventId

        ...
}
```

Comment: Do you use Oracle ??? You said: SQL throws an exception when it try to insert MatImage with #0 as matId. Ok, but can you show how do you save a MatImage object ??

Comment: and what is your question actually? State it clearly.

Comment: Is the Mat saved before set to MatImage?

Comment: No, I am using PostgreSQL. I save MatImage by session.saveOrUpdate(matImage) in general. And Mat is saved before this is done. To clarify, I was trying to avoid seting matId since it is the same id in Mat. ie. mat.setMatImage(matImage); matImage.setMat(mat); and have matid synchronized with id from Mat object. Thank you for all the comments. Any suggestion would help. 

P.S. I found out @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn need to be on matImage(owned) and JoinColumn gets ignore with mappedby.

Answer (score 4):

I am not sure about you really want. But you can use something like the following one to set up your bidirectional relationship.

```
@Entity
public class Mat implements Serializable {

    private MutableInt id = new Mutable(-1);

    private MatImage matImage;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO, generator="SeqMat")
    @SequenceGenerator(name="SeqMat", sequenceName="seq_mat_id")
    public Integer getId() {
        return this.id.intValue;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id.setValue(id)
    }

    public void setIdAsMutableInt(MutableInt id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @OneToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn
    @Cascade({CascadeType.ALL, CascadeType.DELETE_ORPHAN})
    public MatImage getMatImage() {
        return this.matImage;
    }

    public void setMatImage(MatImage matImage) {
        this.matImage = matImage;

        this.matImage.setIdAsMutableInt(this.id);
    }

}
```

Now our `MatImage`

```
@Entity
public class MatImage implements Serializable {

    private MutableInt id = new MutableInt(-1);

    private Mat mat;

    @Id
    public Integer getId() {
        return this.id.intValue();
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id.setValue(id);
    }

    public void setIdAsMutableInt(MutableInt id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @OneToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn
    public Mat getMat() {
        return mat;
    }

    public void setMat(Mat mat) {
        this.mat = mat;

        this.mat.setIdAsMutableInt(this.id);
    }

}
```

A couple of advice

> JPA specification does not include a standardized method **to deal with the problem of shared primary key generation**

It explains why I use a [`org.apache.commons.lang.mutable.MutableInt`](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-2.3/org/apache/commons/lang/mutable/MutableInt.html) **as a way both `Mat` and `MatImage` share the same object (id) in memory**.

Now you can use something like:

```
Mat mat = new Mat();
MatImage matImage = new MatImage();

/**
  * Set up both sides
  * 
  * Or use some kind of add convenience method To take car of it
  */
mat.setImage(matImage);
matImage.setMat(mat);

session.saveOrUpdate(mat);
```

Both will share the same generated id.

Advice: put annotation configuration in getter method instead of member field. Hibernate makes use of proxy objects. But proxy works fine when using annotation in getter method, not when using in member field.

regards,

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that JPA, by default, will not allow proper annotations for bi-directional, shared keys, one-to-one relationships. Hibernate has the perfect construct just for that, but please mind the order properly, as well as the specific parameters to the annotations (you can also read the hibernate reference, but their example will not work unless you preset the dependent object first, which can be avoided with the method bellow - which basically saves both objects automatically, in one go).
In this example, each job is processing a message. Job is the "parent" and message is the dependent object. The primary key of message will be the job id (for eliminating one extra column in the message table. You can also create an id in the message table, if you need to use message outside the job scope, using the same setup as bellow). When a job is created and a message attached, hibernate will automatically save both objects when jobDao.save is called.

```
@Entity
@Table
public class Job implements Serializable{
private Long id;
@Id
    @GeneratedValue
    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

 @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "job")
    public Message getMessage() {
        return message;
    }

    public void setMessage(Message message) {
        this.message = message;
        message.setJob(this);
    }
}
```

And now the dependent message:

```
@Entity
@Table
public abstract class Message implements Serializable {

private Job job;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "foreign")
    @GenericGenerator(
            name = "foreign",
            strategy = "foreign",
            parameters = {@org.hibernate.annotations.Parameter(name = "property", value = "job")})
    @OneToOne(optional = false, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    public Job getJob() {
        return job;
    }

    public void setJob(Job job) {
        this.job = job;
    }

}
```