# Hibernate+JPA One To One relationship

Tags: hibernate, jpa, relationship, one-to-one

I have a OneToOne relationship like this :-

```
Person                            Others
-----------                      ------------- 
| id  (PK) |  <----------------->| id(PK)(FK) |
-----------                      -------------
| name     |                     |....        |
| address  |                     |....        |
| ....     |                     |....        |
```

Here person table's id is auto-generated, but Others table's id is a foreign key. How can I link these two tables.

Comment: possible duplicate of [@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn with Bidirectional @OneToOne relationship ](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2001007/primarykeyjoincolumn-with-bidirectional-onetoone-relationship)

Comment: See also [JPA Hibernate One-to-One relationship](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/787698/jpa-hibernate-one-to-one-relationship)

Answer (score 0):

You can forget about the foreign key stuff and keep coninue in normal one to one mapping relation.For more details [how to connect two tables when one has no primary key](http://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/hibernate-one-to-one-relationship-example/)