# JPA composite key issue: Column 'Person_ID' cannot be null

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

this is hurdle number 43 tonight in trying to get JPA/Hibernate working in a new project.

When trying to create and then persist my `Staffer` class, I get:

```
SEVERE: Column 'Person_ID' cannot be null
SEVERE: Could not synchronize database state with session
```

`Staffer` contains a `Person`, an `Office`, and a `Location`, with the `Person` being the primary key. I'm manually creating each of theses entities, persisting them, attaching them, verifying that they are not null, that their ids are not null, and then persisting my `Staffer`.

I can't figure out why JPA/Hibernate is complaining about an (apparently) null person field when I try to persist:

```
    EntityManager em = EMF.get().createEntityManager();
    em.getTransaction().begin();
    Location location = new Location();
    location.setCity("my city");
    location = em.merge(location);
    assertNotNull(location.getId());

    Office office = new Office();
    office.setName("my office");
    office.setLocation(location);
    office = em.merge(office);
    assertNotNull(office.getId());

    Person person = new Person();
    person.setFirstName("first");
    person.setLastName("last");
    person = em.merge(person);
    assertNotNull(person.getId());

    Staffer staffer = new Staffer();
    staffer.setPerson(person);
    staffer.setCellPhone("555-555-5555");
    staffer.setOffice(office);
    staffer.setHomeLocation(location);
    staffer.setPersonalEmail("me@home.com");

    assertNotNull(staffer.getPerson());
    assertNotNull(staffer.getPerson().getId());
    staffer = em.merge(staffer);  // CODE FAILS HERE
    em.getTransaction().commit();
```

Here is my model code:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Staffer")
public class Staffer implements Serializable
{
    @Id
    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)
    @JoinColumn(name = "Person_ID")
    private Person person;

    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)
    @JoinColumn(name = "Office_ID")
    private Office office;

    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)
    @JoinColumn(name = "Home_Address_Location_ID")
    private Location homeLocation;   

    @Column(name = "Home_Phone")
    private String homePhone;

    @Column(name = "Cell_Phone")
    private String cellPhone;

    @Column(name = "Personal_Email")
    private String personalEmail;

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o)
    {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;

        Staffer staffer = (Staffer) o;

        if (homeLocation != null ? !homeLocation.equals(staffer.homeLocation) : staffer.homeLocation != null)
            return false;
        if (office != null ? !office.equals(staffer.office) : staffer.office != null) return false;
        if (person != null ? !person.equals(staffer.person) : staffer.person != null) return false;

        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode()
    {
        int result = person != null ? person.hashCode() : 0;
        result = 31 * result + (office != null ? office.hashCode() : 0);
        result = 31 * result + (homeLocation != null ? homeLocation.hashCode() : 0);
        return result;
    }

    // getters & setters, etc.
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "Person")
public class Person
{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "Person_ID")
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "First_Name")
    private String firstName;

    @Column(name = "Last_Name")
    private String lastName;
    // getters & setters, etc.
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "Office")
public class Office
{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy= GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "Office_ID")
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "Name")
    private String name;

    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)
    @JoinColumn(name = "Location_ID")
    private Location location;

    // getters & setters, etc.
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "Location")
public class Location
{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy= GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "Location_ID")
    private Long id;

    @Column(name ="City")
    private String city;

    // getters & setters, etc.
}
```

Also, I'm not sure why when the table is created by Hibernate, it creates the Home_Address_Location_ID and Office fields as part of the key for Staffer; my intention is to only use the Person as primary key.

```
+--------------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field                    | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+--------------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Cell_Phone               | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |       | 
| Home_Phone               | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |       | 
| Personal_Email           | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |       | 
| Person_ID                | bigint(20)   | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       | 
| Home_Address_Location_ID | bigint(20)   | YES  | MUL | NULL    |       | 
| Office_ID                | bigint(20)   | YES  | MUL | NULL    |       | 
+--------------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

Comment: Perhaps it's a bug in Hibernate, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4027623/how-do-i-properly-cascade-save-a-one-to-one-bidirectional-relationship-on-primar

Comment: axtavt- perhaps, but in my case the relationship is not bi-directional.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me `Staffer` is really a subclass of `Person`. I would model it this way (Hibernate will be happier). Probably using a table-per-subclass setup.

Other options include a surrogate id on `Staffer` (ugh) or some sort of embedded ID voodoo (haven't thought that last one through).

Comment: Yeah, it does appear that Staffer is a kind of Person. This is a sort of tortured process because I was given SQL by a client, and am trying to create model classes that will come as close as possible to generating the SQL that the client desires.  Surrogate ID? I'll have to look that up.  Thanks.

Comment: @CaffeineComa a surrogate ID is a "fake" ID you assign to an entity because for some reason you don't want to use the natural key as a primary key. In this case, you would need an extra ID column in your Staffer table. I do not think it is the optimal solution here because it introduces a completely useless ID, as Person - Staffer is always a one to one relationship (every staffer is a person, so why would he need a new identifier?). But it would be a workaround, if you can change the database.