# Java/Hibernate/JPA: cannot persist with compound key -> transient object

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

my problem is that I cannot save my entity because it contains another entity, mapped by a key that is also a part of this table's primary key. The table looks like this:

```
table C:

+-----+------+
| id_A | id_B |
+-----+------+
```

..where idA is the primary key of table A with `EntityA` and idB the primary key of table B with `EntityB`.

so its basically a n-to-m relation. This is the entity I'm using for table C:

```
@Entity
public class EntityC {

    private long idA;
    private EntityB b;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id_A")
    public long getIdA() {
        return idA;
    }

    @Id
    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "id_B")
    public EntityB getB() {
        return b;
    }

    ...setters are here...

}
```

Please note that `id_A` is mapped as is (the id), while `id_B` is mapped as its object representation, `EntityB`. This is what I want to do with it:

```
EntityC c = new EntityC();
c.setIdA(123);
c.setB(new EntityB());

em.persist(c);
tx.commit();
em.close();
```

I want to persist `EntityB` ONLY IF I can persist `EntityC`.

on `tx.commit()` I get this exception: `org.hibernate.TransientObjectException: object references an unsaved transient instance`

I suppose this happens because part of the primary key, `id_B`, is not saved. But i set cascading to all so there should be no problem!

Why is this not working?

---

EDIT:

When I do this:

```
em.persist(c.getB());
em.persist(c);
```

it works. But can't Hibernate/JPA do that automatically? I thought that's what cascading is good for.

---

EDIT2:

added an embeddedId instead of id_A and id_B:

```
@Embeddable
public class EntityCID implements Serializable {

public long idA;

@OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(name = "id_B", referencedColumnName = "id")
public EntryB b;

}
```

EntityC now looks like:

```
@Entity
public class EntityC implements Serializable {

    private EntityCID id;
    ...

    @EmbeddedId
    public void getId() {
        return id;
    }

}
```

but I still get the transient object exception if I don't `em.persist(c.getId().b);` before `em.persist(c)`. Sticking to that, although it is ugly.

@Trein: it is not bidirectional. EntityB code:

```
@Entity
public class EntityB implements Serializable {
    public long id;
    public String text;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you think about it what you are seeing makes perfect sense.

EntityC is is the 'owning side' of the relationship C<>B: it defines the JoinColumn and EntityB has the 'mappedBy' attribute.

So on saving C, order of events would normally be:

- insert into C/update C
- insert into B/update B

Now in your case this causes issues as obviously C can only be saved if B has been persisted first.

In terms of your statement above: I want to persist "EntityB ONLY IF I can persist EntityC." How can this ever be the case?

JPA has a concept of 'Derived Identifiers', which I am not overly familiar with however is defined in the book Pro JPA as occurring when:

> When an identifier in one entity includes a foreign key to another
>   entity, we call it a derived identifier. Because the entity containing
>   the derived identifier depends upon another entity for its identity,
>   we call the first the dependent entity. The entity that it depends
>   upon is the target of a many-to-one or one-toone relationship from the
>   dependent entity, and is called the parent entity

Now, despite the original advice that you had two @Id attributes defined and this was wrong it would however appear that having an additional @Id on a 1-2-m is in fact valid in JPA 2 for precisely this case.

The book gives a number of ways of dealing with Derived Identifiers however one example given below looks fairly similar to your case. So you may want to investigate further the @MapsId attribute.

```
@Entity
public class Project {

@EmbeddedId private ProjectId id;
@MapsId("dept")
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumns({
@JoinColumn(name="DEPT_NUM", referencedColumnName="NUM"),
@JoinColumn(name="DEPT_CTRY", referencedColumnName="CTRY")})
private Department department;
// ...
}

@Embeddable
public class ProjectId implements Serializable {

@Column(name="P_NAME")
private String name;
@Embedded
private DeptId dept;
// ...
}
```

See further:

[How do I properly cascade save a one-to-one, bidirectional relationship on primary key in Hibernate 3.6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4027623/how-do-i-properly-cascade-save-a-one-to-one-bidirectional-relationship-on-prima)

Answer (score 0):

Is it a bidirectional relationship? I would suggest you to remove `@Id` `getB()` and perform the modifications:

```
@OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "id_B")
@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name = "id_B")
public EntityB getB() {
    return b;
}
```

Your entity class must have only one attribute annotated with `@Id`. Usually when you need this, you create a class that will store both properties and this will act as a Id Class.

Comment: If I do that, I get an error from hibernate: NonUniqueObjectException. I suppose it is because then hibernate takes id_A as the sole id and does not allow to persist multiple objects with the same id.

Comment: Actually, if you are getting this error it is because Hibernate is complaining that the current `Session` already contains an object with the same ID as a new object that you're trying to save. Can you post the content of `EntityB`?

Comment: I correct myself: tried it again and got a "javax.persistence.EntityExistsException: a different object with the same identifier value was already associated with the session" exception instead. I want to save multiple entities with the same id_A at once.

Comment: Well, if you have to modify a object that is already persisted, you must t retrieve it from database first. You can't just create another instance with the same ID, change it and them persist it. Is that what you are doing?

Comment: I don't want to modify an existing object, I want to create two new ones. It works by the way if I persist `b` manually before persisting `c` (added an example). But is that really the way to go?

Comment: Is it a bidirectional relationship? Can you paste `EntityB`'s code?

Comment: As was noted above Hibernate requires a unique key to function correctly. I would focus firstly on fixing your ID annotations and seeing where that gets you. You can either add another auto-generated ID field to your class C and remove the two  existing @ID annotations or you can use a composite PK in one of two ways, as outlined here: http://www.objectdb.com/java/jpa/entity/id#Entity_Identification_

Comment: @Trein: not bidirectional, I added EntityB's code, but it is boring.

Comment: @Alan Hay: I tried the EmbeddedId, but I still get the transient object exception if i don't persist my EntityB before EntityC. Sadly, it is not cascading.

Answer (score 0):

You can not pass new Entity() for reference. Because it won't have any values in it(even primary key). So how can hibernate will insert it as foreign key to the table. And cascade will save your parent object if its not saved,no need to call save method for all. But when you passing new object it won't do.

Comment: But the primary key should be generated automatically on persisting? Is there no cascading for children?