# Hibernate doesn't persist a OneToOne modification

Tags: hibernate, jpa

Here is the simplified code related to the bug:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "ms_filter", uniqueConstraints=@UniqueConstraint(columnNames = { "ms_id" }))
public class MSFilter

@OneToOne
private MS ms;
```

You ca see that there is a constraint on ms_id.

A new instance of this class is created. ms field is set to a value (a MS) with an sqlId (it's primary key) equals to "1649809", this field is mapped to ms_id. At this time there is already another MSFilter pointing to the same MS, both instances have been committed for long date.

Then I change the value of the field ms to another MS with sqlId equals to 1618544 (a new MS in this session). This is is done by reflection, the setter method is invoked.

Then a commit is called. But I can see that Hibernate tries to save the new entity but with the old value for MS. Here the logs I've added just before the commit. All MSFilters instances of the session are listed (I've put logs in constructor to check this).

> ref: [1] ms_id 1649627 filter_id 1657507 unique_key -2011976030:-1667727498:3:6 user_id null user_profile null id 1657509
>
> ref: [2] ms_id 1649809 filter_id 1657507 unique_key 13321113:-1720593839:2:3076 user_id null user_profile null id 1659533
>
> current: [3] ms_id 1618362 filter_id 1626084 unique_key 1196133270:-1667727498:3:6 user_id null user_profile null id 1628109
>
> current: [4] ms_id 1619159 filter_id 1626084 unique_key 1196133270:-1667727498:1:2 user_id null user_profile null id 1628108
>
> current: [5] ms_id 1618544 filter_id 1626084 unique_key 1196133270:null user_id null user_profile null id 1659620

I did activate Hibernate logs and here is the first and only SQL statement:

> 2015-04-01 01:55:53 DEBUG SQL:109 - insert into ms_filter (ms_id, filter_id, unique_key, user_id, user_profile, id) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
>
> 2015-04-01 01:55:53 TRACE BasicBinder:81 - binding parameter [1] as [INTEGER] - [1649809]
>
> 2015-04-01 01:55:53 TRACE BasicBinder:81 - binding parameter [2] as [INTEGER] - [1626084]
>
> 2015-04-01 01:55:53 TRACE BasicBinder:81 - binding parameter [3] as [VARCHAR] - [1196133270:null]
>
> 2015-04-01 01:55:53 TRACE BasicBinder:69 - binding parameter [4] as [VARCHAR] - [null]
>
> 2015-04-01 01:55:53 TRACE BasicBinder:69 - binding parameter [5] as [VARCHAR] - [null]
>
> 2015-04-01 01:55:53 TRACE BasicBinder:81 - binding parameter [6] as [INTEGER] - [1659620]

As you can see Hibernate tries to insert the instance [5] (if I consider the "id" column). But the value for "ms_id" is not the good one ? And of course the unique constraint is not respected and the transaction fails.

What could cause this ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I properly cascade save a one-to-one, bidirectional relationship on primary key in Hibernate 3.6](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4027623/how-do-i-properly-cascade-save-a-one-to-one-bidirectional-relationship-on-prima)

Comment: thanks for the answer, but my problem is different, I don't have bidirectional association.

Comment: Finaly I found the reason to my problem, it is explained here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29424614/does-jpa-authorize-to-call-em-persist-on-an-instance-persisted-by-cascade