# Hibernate/JPA: could not set a field value by reflection setter

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

My JPA/Hibernate odyssey continues...

I am trying to work around [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4027623/how-do-i-properly-cascade-save-a-one-to-one-bidirectional-relationship-on-primar), and so I have had to define primitive @Ids in my class that uses 3 entity fields as a composite key. This seems to get me a bit further, but now I'm getting this when persisting:

```
javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.PropertyAccessException: could not set a field value by reflection setter of com.example.model.LanguageSkill.stafferId
```

Here's my composite class:

```
public class LanguageSkill implements Serializable
{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue (strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "Staffer_ID")
    private Long stafferId;

    @Id
    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @MapsId(value = "stafferId")
    private Staffer staffer;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue (strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "Language_ID")
    private Long languageId;

    @ManyToOne
    @MapsId(value= "languageId")
    private Language language;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue (strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "Language_Proficiency_ID")
    private Long languageProficiencyId;

    @ManyToOne
    @MapsId(value= "languageProficiencyId")
    private LanguageProficiency languageProficiency;
}
```

I do have proper getters and setters (IDE-generated) for both the primitives as well as the entities.

Here are my libs. I'm not totally convinced that I'm using a compatible set of persistence libraries (references to a cookbook detailing how to properly mix-and-match these would be highly appreciated.)

- Hibernate 3.5.6-SNAPSHOT
- hibernate-jpamodelgen 1.1.0.CR1
- hibernate-validator 3.1.0.GA
- MySQL 5.1.6
- jsr250-api 1.0
- javax.validation validation-api 1.0.0.GA

Wow, it's frustrating. 3 days now full time trying to solve various issues like this just for basic ORM. I feel defective. :-(

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2001007/2039553#2039553

Comment: Thanks Arthur, but in my case it's a uni-directional relationship. Also, I did try moving my annotations to the getters, but that didn't seem to help.

Comment: Do you have `@IdClass`? Also remove `@Id` from `staffer`.

Comment: axtavt- I tried @IdClass. I get yet another, more bizarre error from that: "Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Parameter index out of range (5 > number of parameters, which is 4)." And yes, you're quite correct that @Id should be removed from Staffer, since it's defined on the primitive, thanks.

Comment: Did you find a solution to this problem? I'm facing something similar...

Comment: Using Hibernate 4 Beta5 and I'm also getting a strange "Parameter index out of range" exception when trying to persist an entity with 3 fields on MySQL 5.

Comment: I was able to defeat Hibernate with the strange "Parameter index out of range" problem. The problem was that when using JPA 1.0 compatible Mappings (redundant `@Column`s) only these or the relationship columns may be writable `(..., insertable = false, updatable = false)`. Hibernate has always had problems when the above readonly is put onto the redundant `@Column` fields. Just move them to the relationships and you might be fine. Another plain horrible Hibernate **BUG**... (all recent versions)

Answer (score 1):

It seems a correct code. I had problem with this exception when I used Blob[]

```
@Lob
@Column(name="DOCUMENTO",nullable=false)
private Blob[] documento;
```

But changing by Byte[], I solved this problem.

I have only a occurrence, looking Oracle data types, I have seen this **LONG is Character data of variable length (A bigger version the VARCHAR2 datatype).**

I assume that your ID is a Integer....Why not change Long by Integer? You must remember that it only accepts primitive types.

This is my code and it works fine:

```
@Id
@SequenceGenerator(sequenceName="SQ_DOCUMENTO",name="seqDocumento")
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.SEQUENCE,generator="seqDocumento")
private Integer idDocumento;
```

I use Hibernate 3.5.6-final, Spring 3.0.4, Junit 4 and Oracle 11g.

Answer (score -1):

You have to remove the `@GeneratedValue` annotations.