# Hibernate/JPA 2.0 @OneToOne relationship with possibly non existent matching rows

Tags: hibernate, jpa-2.0, one-to-one

I have two tables, let's say **Person and Person_info**. Both tables have **shared PK person_id** which is also used as a Foreign key.
The situation is, there can exist Person for which doesn't exist Person_info. **Person_info is optional for person**, there does not need to exist row with the same person_id.
When I want to search for persons with hibernate, e.g.:

```
Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(Person.class);
criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("name", name));
Object obj = criteria.uniqueResult();
```

I get an exception:

```
 [<package>.PersonInfo#338664] org.hibernate.ObjectNotFoundException: No row with the given identifier exists:  <package>.PersonInfo#338664]
```

Of course Person_info row with person_id=338664 really doesn't exist. But I still would like hibernate to be able to handle this. **If the row exists, then I want to load it, if it doesn't I want to get null**, not an exception.

I am using hibernate version 3.5.6-Final. 
I think this thread is exactly about the same problem, but there is no solution in it [@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn with Bidirectional @OneToOne relationship](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2001007/primarykeyjoincolumn-with-bidirectional-onetoone-relationship)

Thank you for your help.

The annotated classes look like this:

Person class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="Person")
public class Person extends BaseDBEntity<Integer>{
    private PersonInfo personInfo;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name="person_id")
    public Integer getId() {
      return id;
    }

    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, optional = true)
    @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn
    public PersonInfo getPersonInfo() {
      return personInfo;
    }
}
```

PersonInfo class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="Person_info")
public class PersonInfo extends BaseDBEntity<Integer> {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name="person_id")
    public Integer getId() {
      return id;
    }
}
```

Both of them inherit from BaseDBEntity:

```
public abstract class BaseDbEntity<T> implements Serializable {

      private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

      protected T id;
}
```

Comment: Except for the ID generation of PersonInfo, this looks correct to me. Have you tried with a more recent version of Hibernate? 3.5.6 is quite old.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is known bug: [HHH-4982](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-4982) (*JPA OneToOne(optional=true) not supported with @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn*).

Problem can be solved by updating to newer version. Bug is fixed in 3.6.8, but likely it makes sense to update to 3.6.10, if going for Hibernate 4 is not an option.

Comment: Thank you. We went with a workaround at last, using \@JoinColumn instead of \@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn to avoid hardcore testing of the whole application.

Comment: Same problem but different workaround: I used @NotFound(IGNORE) annotation from Hibernate (not JPA)